# How to proof that this improper integral diverges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am trying to show that
$\int_\pi^\infty \mid\frac{sin(x)}{x}\mid dx$ does not converge.

My approach:
I noticed that $\frac{sin(k\pi)}{k\pi}=0$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$\{0}

Now i "split up" the function like this
$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \mid\frac{sin(x)}{x} \mid dx$

My Problem is that I can't find a estimate (that diverges) and is less or equal to the term above.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> This is probably answered elsewhere on-site, but the "obvious" isosceles triangles inscribed under the graph suffice. :)

Comment: The word "proof" is a noun.  The word "prove" is a verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

trying to split the sum is the right idea :)
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{\pi}^{n\pi}\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|\,\mathrm{d}x&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|\cdot|\sin(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\geq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{1}{(k+1)\pi}\cdot|\sin(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\geq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(k+1)\pi}\cdot\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}|\sin(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(k+1)\pi}\cdot 2\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} \left| \frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\,dx \ge \frac{1}{(k+1)\pi} \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} |\sin x|\,dx.$$

Comment: @ zhw. got it, thanks for the hint

Comment: @zhw.  Hope all is well.  I've received a couple of messages (warnings) from the MSE moderators regarding my answering (1) "low quality" questions and (2) duplicate questions.  And in addition, I've received several downvotes coincidentally.  So, I'm wondering if you've received similar messages from the moderators.

Comment: @MarkViola Sorry to hear that. I haven't received any emails from MSE in the last several years.